# Cannot record voice in a webview

Tags: android, webview, audio-recording

Inside Android webview I consistent get a PermissionDenied error back from a call to navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia despite asking for permission first.

My process starts with a call to StartRecordAudio function below with the CheckPermissionFirst parameter set to true if working in Android.

```
var AudioRecorder ; // recorder
var RawAudioDataArray ; // raw recorded data
var AudioSaveFormat = "audio/wav" ; // waveform audio - alternatives "audio/mpeg-3" and "audio/webm" ;
var AudioStartCallback ; // function to be called at start of input
var AudioErrorCallback ; // function to be called if audio cannot be recorded (no capability orno permission)
var AudioDoneCallback ; // function to be called at end of input

function StartRecordAudio (CheckPermissionFirst,StartCallback,ErrorCallback,DoneCallback) 
{
AudioStartCallback = StartCallback ; 
AudioErrorCallback = ErrorCallback ; 
AudioDoneCallback  = DoneCallback ; 
RawAudioDataArray = [] ;
if (AudioRecorder)
    {
    StartRecording ();
    }
else if (CheckPermissionFirst)
    {
    CheckAppMicrophonePermission ()
    } 
else
    {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ({audio:true}).then (AudioDeviceFound).catch (AudioErrorCallback); 
    };
};
```

CheckAppMicrophonePermission is as follows

```
function CheckAppMicrophonePermission ()
{
AndroidBridge.call ("CheckMicrophonePermission" , []);
};
```

Skipping over the details of the AndroidBridge, this call triggers the following java function in the Android wrapper code

```
if ("CheckMicrophonePermission".equals(command))
    {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission (MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions (MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, requestMicrophoneId );
        }
    else
        {
        MicrophonePermissionsOK ();
        }
    }
```

which when finished interrogating the user will call

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)
    {
    switch (requestCode)
        {
        case requestMicrophoneId:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                MicrophonePermissionsOK();
                break;
                }
            else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
                {
                MicrophonePermissionsNOTOK(false);
                }
            else
                {
                MicrophonePermissionsNOTOK(true);
                };
            break;
        }
    }
```

Function MicrophonePermissionsOK is as follows :

```
public void MicrophonePermissionsOK ()
{
String jsString = "AppMicrophonePermissionGranted()";
mWebView.evaluateJavascript (jsString);
}
```

Back on the original side of the Android Bridge

```
function AppMicrophonePermissionGranted ()
{
AndroidMicrophonePermission = true ; 
ShowAlert ("Please select OK to activate the app microphone link");
AlertCallback = function () {HideAlert (); AudioPermissionGranted ()};
};
```

Finally when the user ok's my custom alert dialog (details of this function irrelevant here I think), we get to:

```
function AudioPermissionGranted ()
{
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ({audio:true}).then (AudioDeviceFound).catch (AudioErrorCallback); 

};
```

For anyone interested the promise success route is to

```
function AudioDeviceFound (Stream)
{
AudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder (Stream);
AudioRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e)
    {
    RawAudioDataArray.push (e.data);
    if (AudioRecorder.state == "inactive") // recorder has been stopped either by user or after max seconds
        {
        var blob = new Blob (RawAudioDataArray, {type:AudioSaveFormat});
        var reader = new FileReader ();
        reader.onload = function () {AudioDoneCallback (reader.result.split (',')[1])};
        reader.readAsDataURL (blob);
        };    
    };
StartRecording ();
};

function StartRecording ()
{
AudioStartCallback ();
AudioRecorder.start (1000); // record in 1 second chunks
SetAudioTimeout ();
};

function SetAudioTimeout ()
{
AudioTimeout = window.setTimeout (function () {AudioRecorder.stop(); 
AudioTimeout = null}, MaxAudioSeconds * 1000);
};
```

All of this code works fine on Chrome and inside a Chrome Packaged App.

However I have traced the code inside an Android webview and I get the correct sequence of actions right through all the code up until invoking the getUserMedia promise.

This is the case for a new loaded app or an existing loaded app. Also when the permission has not been requested before, when the permission has been requested denied and when the permission is granted, both through the permission dialog shown above directly in the settings app.

However (in Android webview), invoking the getUserMedia promise always triggers the catch condition with error parameter name set to PermissionDenied and the message set to empty string.

Please can someone help me?